# Unable to register external kubernetes cluster with GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to set up a multi-cloud deployment using GKE as a single plain of glass for cluster management. Unfortunately, I can't see "Register cluster" option within GKE. I can create a cluster, I can delete a cluster, I can deploy a workload to a cluster, but the option with registering the new cluster is not available for me.

I'm not using the free tier and I'm not within an Organisation also.

Could somebody help me to figure out why it is so? I could not find the solution digging through GCP documentation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/). It has a [unified user interface](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/anthos-overview#unified_user_interface) and in the [Anthos for operations](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/anthos-overview#for_operations) section of the documentation it says:

> Single pane of glass visibility across all clusters ...

But the link to the documentation to [register a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/connect/registering-a-cluster) gives me a 404.... I would suggest reaching out to Google Cloud Support to see if they can help you.

---

edit: It turns out that you need to be an Anthos customer to access the both the feature and the documentation for the feature.